# Updated pandas: Now lambda & to_list() not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, lambda

I have a dataframe (7780,4), two columns (Start & End) are datetimes and i'd like to create a 5th column (Range) where each entry contains a list of datetimes between 'Start' and 'End'.

I used to have the following code which worked, however now that i've updated my packages i'm getting the following error.

"ValueError: Shape of passed values is (7780, 49), indices imply (7780, 5)"

```py
DF["Range"] = DF.apply(lambda row:pd.date_range(start=row['Start'], end=row['End'], freq='30min').tolist(), axis=1)
```

I believe the issue is due to the update to pandas, however i'm not sure.

Would appreciate if someone could help out!

Thanks

Josh

Comment: You don't need to call "to_list" method. Pandas will automatically assign the result of the lambda function.

Comment: When I remove to_list() I now receive the error message 'Length of values does not match length of index'.

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue. The code works with and without `tolist()` in my simple tests. Are you sure the problem in this very line? Provide full error traceback and sample data.

Comment: Thanks for the help - this turned out to be a silly error whereby I was using a very old version of pandas